# Disable finger gestures for Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, electron, screen

We have an Electron app with React.js deployed in a Raspberry pi 4 B with Ubuntu 20 connected to a screen. We want to have the app running every time and the user shouldn't close it (only if you connect a keyboard and press Alt+Tab).

The screen is touchable and we want to disable the finger gestures because the user can with 3 finger up exit from the fullscreen. The screen seems that's well connected, however, in setting doesn't appear anything about the screen configuration. We heard something about kiosk mode but it doesn't work.

[The screen is the following one](https://www.tiendatec.es/raspberry-pi/pantallas/1383-monitor-7-tactil-1024x600-ips-hdmi-8472496019095.html)

Thank you!